# How to get the logged in user's real name in Unix?

Tags: unix

I'm looking to find out the logged in user's real (full name) to avoid having to prompt them for it in an app I'm building. I see the `finger` command will output a columned list of data that includes this and was wondering if it makes sense to grep through this or is there an easier way? None of the switches for finger that I've found output just the real name. Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: How about `finger smith | sed -e '/Name/!d' -e 's/.*Name: //'`?

Comment: Right on Beta, that worked beautifully. Do you think that this is safe if there is more than one logged in user? Specifically does your sed magic above return all real name's or just the first one it encounters? Thanks!

Comment: Or: `finger blah | grep Name | awk -F "Name:" '{print $2}'`
These will work fine if there are multiple users. It just pulls the one specified.

Comment: Cool, thanks arkigos. This works great too, cheers!

Comment: Come to think of it: `finger smith | sed -e '/Name/!d;s/.*: //'`

Comment: Not perfect, but: `finger | egrep -m 1 -o '[ ][^ ]+[ ][^ ]+[ ]'`

Answer (score 18):

```
getent passwd `whoami` | cut -d : -f 5
```

(`getent` is usually preferable to grepping `/etc/passwd`).

Comment: This only works on UNIXen with `getent`; macOS is not one of them.

Comment: @fluffy quite true. Use `id -F` instead (this replaces the entire command above).

Comment: Ah, nice! That's way easier than using `dscl` :)

Comment: You don't really need the `whoami` call there.  `getent passwd "$USER"`

Comment: Produces on recent Debians "User Name,,," with three trailing commas.

Answer (score 7):

```sh
getent passwd "$USER" | cut -d: -f5 | cut -d, -f1
```

This first fetches the current user's line from the `passwd` database (which might also be stored on *NIS* or *LDAP*)

In the fetched line, fields are separated by `:` delimiters. The **GECOS** entry is the 5th field, thus the first `cut` extracts that.

The **GECOS** entry itself is possibly composed of multiple items - separated by `,` - of which the full name is the first item. That's what the second `cut` extracts. This also works if the **GECOS** entry is lacking the commas. In that case the whole entry is the first item.

You can also assign the result to a variable:

```sh
fullname=$( getent passwd "$USER" | cut -d: -f5 | cut -d, -f1 )
```

Or process it further directly:

```sh
echo "$( getent passwd "$USER" | cut -d: -f5 | cut -d, -f1 )'s home is $HOME."
```

```sh
cat <<EOF
Hello, $( getent passwd "$USER" | cut -d: -f5 | cut -d, -f1 ).
How are you doing?
EOF
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [getpwent()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwent) to get each successive password entry until you find the one that matches the currently logged in user, then parse the [gecos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecos_field) field.

Better, you can use [getpwuid()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwuid) to directly get the entry for the uid of the current user.

In either case,

1. You have to first get the current user's login name or id, and
2. There is no guarantee that the gecos field actually contains the user's real full name, or anything at all.

Comment: Unfortunately, this works neither on macOS (which always returns the string ('AMaViS') nor on Ubuntu Linux (which just returns 'root').

Comment: ...because `getpwent()` goes through each entry in order, rather than going with the current logged-in user's entry. `getpwuid()` is the correct API call.

Comment: Good points fluffy, I haven't revisited this answer in quite a while.

Answer (score 2):

Specific to macOS, there is no `getent` command; instead you have to use `id -F`

Comment: On macOS High Sierra, I had to use a capital `-F`.

Answer (score 1):

For macOS and Linux:

`if [ "Darwin" = $(uname) ]; then
    FULLNAME=$(id -P $USER | awk -F '[:]' '{print $8}')
else
    FULLNAME=$(getent passwd $USER | cut -d: -f5 | cut -d, -f1)
fi
echo $FULLNAME`

Answer (score -1):

I use

```
grep "^$USER:" /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{print $5}'
```

Explanations:

- $USER contains the login of the current user
- The first part (`grep`) extract from `/etc/passwd` the line about that user
- The second part (`awk`) splits this line with separator `':'` and prints the 5th component,
  which is the full name

If you don't want to rely on `$USER` being set, you can use that instead:

```
grep "^`whoami`:" /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{print $5}'
```

Comment: That's a [useless use of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep).  You want `awk -v u="$USER" '$1 == u { print $5 }'`

Comment: And both are a useless use of third-party tools instead of coreutils.

Answer (score -2):

How about trying whoami or logname

Comment: whoami or logname output the username logged in, not the "full name" assigned to the account as he's requesting