# Getting the current user account's display name in UNIX-type operating systems

Tags: linux, macos, unix, cross-platform

In Windows, the user account has both an account name and a "real name" associated with the account. This can be retrieved by [`GetUserNameEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724435(v=vs.85).aspx).

Similarly, in UNIX-type operating systems, there's the "finger info" (as set by `chfn` and the like, as well as through various GUI tools on desktop UNIXen). How can this information be retrieved by a user process in UNIX-type OSes (such as macOS and Linux)?

An ideal solution would use the libc API, without relying on just spawning a `finger` process or the like.

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619277/how-to-get-the-logged-in-users-real-name-in-unix

Comment: @Sundeep Yes! `getpwent` seems to be in the right direction. Thanks. Also this question should be closed as duplicate :)

Comment: Hm, at least on OSX, `getpwent` doesn't actually return the information I need, but the question is still a duplicate. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the logged in user's real name in Unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619277/how-to-get-the-logged-in-users-real-name-in-unix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably call `getuid`, then `getpwuid` or `getpwuid_r`, on Unix-like systems.

Something like:

```
#include <pwd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main(void)
{
    struct passwd *pw;

    pw = getpwuid(getuid());

    if (pw == 0) {
        perror("getpwuid failed");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("username: %s; realname: '%s'\n", pw->pw_name, pw->pw_gecos);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `pw_gecos` field doesn't provide the realname on macOS, unfortunately (or on Ubuntu either, for that matter).

Comment: Logins need to be created with real names that can be found, presumably, but the above code just worked for me as-is on Mac OS X 10.11.6 (El Capitan), where "cc" was "Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)", and on Ubuntu 16.04, where "cc" was "cc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2) 5.4.0 20160609".

How did you try to get it to work on Mac and Ubuntu?

Comment: Oh, interesting! I'd used `getpwent()` rather than `getpwuid(getuid())`, and that was why it was failing. `getpwuid` worked fine on both machines (macOS 10.12, and Ubuntu 15.10). Thanks!

Comment: Ah, it also turns out that I misunderstood what `getpwent()` actually does. I should have looked more carefully at its manpage, as well as the rest of its output. :)

Answer (score 0):

Shell-scripting solution:

On Linux, you can use `getent passwd` in a subprocess, and then parse out the realname field (which should be the fifth one between commas).

On macOS, you can use `id -f`.